# MySQL: How to query for the number of times since a value was X

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find the fastest and most efficient way to query data to find how many rows since a value was set in a table, with the table sorted by a mysql time field

```
Time     | Login Failed
00:00:01 | 0
00:00:02 | 1
00:00:04 | 0
00:00:05 | 0
```

For this example I'd like to report that there have been two logins since the last failed login. I can't find a simple way to do this, wondered if anyone could help.

Comment: Consider splitting this into two queries: one to find the last failed login and one to count number of logins since a time. You should then be able to join these together for the final result.

Comment: Can you find anyway to do this, simple or otherwise?